# Do C3 charts work inside an LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, charts

[C3](https://c3js.org/) does things like drawing values in pie charts by default, and as it is based on D3 perhaps has sone good animation capabilities. (The LWC [recipe is using Chart.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsChartjs).)

But before I waste hours on trying to get it to work inside an LWC (Lightning Web Component), if you have it working let me know, including the version number you are using.

Comment: Yes, it does. See [this](https://medium.com/@dave_norris/d3js-meet-lwc-a4b8ce71924d) blog by Dave Norris.

Comment: Hi @rahulgawale, Agree that D3 working makes it likely, and there is a D3 recipe https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsD3. C3 is AFAIK a layer on top of D3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went ahead and tried it and it worked fine first time though of course this doesn't guarantee that everything works. I tried D3 v5.7.0 and C3 v0.7.15.

A downside is that the JavaScript is 500k for D3 plus 200k for C3 compared to 200k for Chart.js.

Sample output:

[image: sample output]

from this JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import D3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/d3';
import C3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/c3';

export default class C3WorkforceCountChart extends LightningElement {

    error;
    chart;
    initialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.initialized) return;
        this.initialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, D3 + '/d3.v5.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, D3 + '/style.css'),
            loadScript(this, C3 + '/c3.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, C3 + '/c3.min.css')
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.chart = window.c3.generate({
                    bindto: this.template.querySelector('div.c3-chart'),
                    data: {
                        columns: [
                            ['Active employees', 20],
                            ['Employees on leave', 5],
                        ],
                        type : 'donut',
                        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
                        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
                        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
                    },
                    donut: {
                        title: "25 Employees",
                        expand: true,
                        label: {
                            format: function (value, ratio, id) {
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
}
```

and template:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={error}>
        {error}
    </template>
    <div class="c3-chart" lwc:dom="manual" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    </div>
</template>
```